# Perl catalyst development server not accepting connections

Tags: perl, catalyst

Here is the stdout

```
[lzhou@localhost script]$ perl dbauthtest_server.pl  You are loading Catalyst::Engine::HTTP explicitly.

This is almost certainly a bad idea, as Catalyst::Engine::HTTP has been removed in this version of Catalyst.

Please update your application's scripts with:

  catalyst.pl -force -scripts MyApp

to update your scripts to not do this. [debug] Debug messages enabled [debug] Statistics enabled [warn] You are running an old script!

  Please update by running (this will overwrite existing files):
    catalyst.pl -force -scripts DBAuthTest

  or (this will not overwrite existing files):
    catalyst.pl -scripts DBAuthTest

[debug] Loaded Config "/home/lzhou/ä¸è¼ /def-guide-to-catalyst-master/4439/catalyst-book-code/Chapter_6/DBAuthTest/dbauthtest.conf" [debug] Loaded plugins: .--------------------------------------------------------------------------------. | Catalyst::Plugin::ConfigLoader  0.34                                 | '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

[debug] Loaded PSGI Middleware: .--------------------------------------------------------------------------------. | Catalyst::Middleware::Stash                                          | | Plack::Middleware::HTTPExceptions                                  | | Plack::Middleware::RemoveRedundantBody  0.06                       | | Plack::Middleware::FixMissingBodyInRedirect  0.12                  | | Plack::Middleware::ContentLength                                   | | Plack::Middleware::MethodOverride  0.20                            | | Plack::Middleware::Head                                            | '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

[debug] Loaded Request Data Handlers: .--------------------------------------------------------------------------------. | application/json                                                     | | application/x-www-form-urlencoded                                  | '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

[debug] Loaded dispatcher "Catalyst::Dispatcher" [debug] Loaded engine "Catalyst::Engine" [debug] Found home "/home/lzhou/ä¸è¼  /def-guide-to-catalyst-master/4439/catalyst-book-code/Chapter_6/DBAuthTest" [debug] Loaded components: .---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------. | Class                                                               | Type     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+ | DBAuthTest::Controller::AuthUsers                                   | instance | | DBAuthTest::Controller::Root                            | instance | | DBAuthTest::Model::AuthDB                               | instance | | DBAuthTest::Model::AuthDB::Roles                        | class    | | DBAuthTest::Model::AuthDB::UserRoles                    | class    | | DBAuthTest::Model::AuthDB::Users                        | class    | | DBAuthTest::View::Web                                   | instance | '---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------'

[debug] Loaded Private actions: .----------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------. | Private              | Class                                | Method |
+----------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------+ | /end                 | DBAuthTest::Controller::Root         | end    | | /default             | DBAuthTest::Controller::Root         | default          | | /authusers/profile   | DBAuthTest::Controller::AuthUsers    | profile          | | /authusers/base      | DBAuthTest::Controller::AuthUsers    | base     | | /authusers/add       | DBAuthTest::Controller::AuthUsers    | add  | | /authusers/user      | DBAuthTest::Controller::AuthUsers    | user | '----------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------'

[debug] Loaded Path actions: .---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------. | Path                                  | Private                      |
+---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+ | /...                                  | /default                     | '---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------'

[debug] Loaded Chained actions: .---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------. | Path Spec                             | Private                      |
+---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+ | /authusers/add                        | /authusers/base (0)          | |                                       | => /authusers/add (0)      | | /authusers/*/profile                  | /authusers/base (0)        | |                                       | -> /authusers/user (1)     | |                                       | => /authusers/profile (0)  | '---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------'

[info] DBAuthTest powered by Catalyst 5.90124
```

But when i visit http://localhost:3000/ , connection is refused . it appears that there is no server running.

Comment: Can you fix the output text? That's not readable.

Comment: Re "*it appears that there is no server*", 1) You are using a browser on the same machine, right? Also try `http://127.0.0.1/`) Well, it is running or not? Check. 3) Use `netstat -a` to see if there's anything listening to port 3000. Also check when the server isn't running to make sure that nothing *else* is already using up the port. 4) Maybe you're running afoul of SELinux or whatever rules.

Comment: And, of course, there's that entire bit about Catalyst::Engine::HTTP

Comment: The second line is "This is almost certainly a bad idea, as Catalyst::Engine::HTTP has been removed in this version of Catalyst.". I'd start investigating there, and follow the instructions it gives you in your output.